# Php DOMDocument in Arabic

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm using MS SQL database item master. The cdescription column is nvarchar data type and display the Arabic encoding when executing a select or view query.

In writing the item master to xml file I'm using DOMDocument::createElement. The xml file is encoded in utf-8 and version 1.0.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->encoding = 'utf-8';
$dom->xmlVersion = '1.0';
$dom->formatOutput = true;    
...
$LineName   = $dom->createElement('cbc:Name', $row['cDescription']); 
$LineItem->appendChild($LineName);  //LineName end
```

However the Arabic values are being replaced with ????? ???? characters.

Comment: Check this: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Right, the `"CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"` in sqlsrv_connect parameters works perfectly!